# server at port 80 seems up, but I can't access it.

Tags: apache-2.2, firewall, remote-access

I can't access my server remotely at port 80. First of all, I did not set it up. Someone else did. I am not a sysadmin. But communication between both parts (me and sysadmin) takes time and deadlines await, so I decided to take matters into my own hands. After all I have root access.

It seems to me there is a Firewall issue, but how can I resolve it?

This is what I get from my side:

```
chris@mint-desktop ~ $ nmap -Pn remote_server -p 80

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-07-01 16:28 EEST
Nmap scan report for remote_server (remote_addr)
Host is up.
rDNS record for remote_addr: rDNS_record_for_remote_addr_seems_valid
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.13 seconds
```

This is what I get server-side:

```
~# ps ax|grep "apache"
 5620 ?        Ss     0:13 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 6203 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep apache
21115 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
21168 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

and...

```
~# netstat -ntlp | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5620/apache2
```

also...

```
~# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Finally

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log
::1 - - [29/Jun/2014:07:35:02 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [29/Jun/2014:07:35:02 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) (internal dummy connection)"
192.168.30.40 - - [30/Jun/2014:15:02:00 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

However, when I hit the remote name on my web browser, I get no response. Logs say that there was a hit yesterday internally, but no external access. So, I guess the sysadmin tested it and realized it was up. But I can't access it.

Comment: It's firewalled somewhere else. What is between you and the server?

Comment: I don't know. I will have to ask...

Comment: What kind of external firewall do you have? This may help aid a sys admin to tell you what to add to your firewall config to open it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a private IP on your server. So you need a DNAT / port forwarding rule on the gateway that directs to port 80 on the web server.

Comment: Thanks. If external request is blocked by a intermediate gateway then I guess there is nothing I can do to fix that. Can I check that myself? Or wait for a sysadmin response?

Comment: If my assumption is true, you need admin access to the router to fix it.